# how to get badge from server to our code

Tags: iphone

in apple push notification service,

- i'm getting badge 50 for my application.
  but i want  that badge number in my code
  i want to save that badge.
  i want  to set that badge somewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to access it with the UIApplication property applicationIconBadgeNumber? You can both read and write this property.

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber
```